# FATAL EXCEPTION Error using HttpClient

Tags: java, android, json, exception, httpclient

I want use JSON and take data form web. And I find a tutorial and I applied whatever. The result was frustration. Briefly:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()

This is my code:

```
package com.example.winsekiz.searchlist;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WebServer extends Activity {


    final static String URI = "www.hocaogluticaret.com/a.html";
    TextView tvData;
    JSONObject json;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.turkey);
        tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        new Game().execute("text");
    }

    protected JSONObject readGameParks() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URI);
        HttpResponse response =client.execute(get);
        StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
        int s = status.getStatusCode();

        if(s == 200) {

            HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONArray posts = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject last = posts.getJSONObject(0);
        }

        return  null;
    }

    public class Game extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try{
                json = readGameParks();
                String data = json.getString(params[0]);
                return  data;
            }

            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data){
            tvData.setText(data);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is error:

```
03-21 22:29:17.110 10922-10922/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-21 22:29:17.120 10922-10922/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist-2/lib/x86_64
03-21 22:29:17.130 10922-10935/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-21 22:29:17.200 10922-10935/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-21 22:29:17.270 10922-10935/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-21 22:29:17.270 10922-10935/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7feb1eea0e40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-21 22:29:18.910 10922-10944/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                                 Process: com.example.winsekiz.searchlist, PID: 10922
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=www.hocaogluticaret.com/a.html
                                                                                     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:603)
                                                                                     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:299)
                                                                                     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
                                                                                     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
                                                                                     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
                                                                                     at com.example.winsekiz.searchlist.WebServer.readGameParks(WebServer.java:47)
                                                                                     at com.example.winsekiz.searchlist.WebServer$Game.doInBackground(WebServer.java:68)
                                                                                     at com.example.winsekiz.searchlist.WebServer$Game.doInBackground(WebServer.java:62)
                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
03-21 22:29:18.990 10922-10935/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-21 22:29:18.990 10922-10935/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7feb1d9ff2c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-21 22:29:19.010 10922-10935/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7feb2e2daa90
03-21 22:29:24.090 10922-10935/com.example.winsekiz.searchlist E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7feb2e2daf60
03-21 22:34:18.920 10922-10944/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10922 SIG: 9
```

Comment: i would suggest using volley for API calls

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild you project. Also make sure you have added the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to your manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets step though the code

1) Start the AsyncTask

```
new Game().execute("text");
```

2) Goes to doInBackground

```
json = readGameParks();
```

3) Connects to a non-qualified URI

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("www.hocaogluticaret.com/a.html");
```

and you get an error, to fix that put `http://` in front of the address.

---

4) Assuming a connection was made appropriately, continue on to `return  null;`

```
String data = json.getString(params[0]);
return  data;
```

Here, `params[0]` is "text", but `json` is null, therefore throwing a `NullPointerException`.

To fix, try not returning `null` in `readGameParks`. I think you should do `return last;` inside the status code check.

---

In code,

```
JSONObject last = new JSONObject();

if(s == 200) {
    HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
    String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
    JSONArray posts = new JSONArray(data);
    last = posts.getJSONObject(0);
}

return last;
```

Comment: With 3. step, so much errors corrected. And now, I have only one error: "E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7feb2e2da5c0" And Virtual Device is showing blank page. And to be honest, I dont understand others.

Comment: Like I told you in the other comment. Look for **Caused by** and read [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The problem is NullPointerException. indirectly  "return last;" I fix it with u. Thank u a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your url is not complete.

```
www.hocaogluticaret.com/a.html
```

should be

```
http://www.hocaogluticaret.com/a.html
```

or

```
https://www.hocaogluticaret.com/a.html
```

Comment: While this is one problem. That is not what the error refers to. `readGameParks` is returning `null`

Comment: Okey. Error codes are now only one. And Virtual Device showing blank page.
Error code is: "getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer."

Comment: Fully error messages are:

emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7feb1d9be1c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7feb2e2da9b0

Comment: @EnesCeylan Look for the words "Caused By". The text you just pasted is not related to the error that was actually caused.

Comment: It might be best to just make a new question, for this, because it seems this is a different problem.